# Netbeans not incluiding resources in built jar file

Tags: java

I have a few text files and a couple of images that i load in my code.
They work fine when i run the program in NetBeans, but when i clean and build the Project, the generated jar file doesn't run, and return an exception showing that the files are not being read.

This is how i load the files:

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> readTextFile(String filePath){
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data = new ArrayList();
        String line;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try{
            //br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath)); 
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filePath))); 
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
                scanner.useDelimiter(Pattern.compile(";"));
                while(scanner.hasNext()){
                    temp.add(scanner.next());
                }
                data.add(temp);
            }
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        }catch (IOException e){
        }finally {
            try {
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            }catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
```

And this is how i'm calling the method:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> loadedData = readTextFile("WeaponVendor.txt");
```

By the way, i inclueded the requiered files by adding them to Project->Properties->Libraries.

In case it's useful, this is the exception i get when running the jar file:

```
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class trabalhoPoo.Game
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:907)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:819)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.io.Reader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at trabalhoPoo.util.fileManager.readTextFile(fileManager.java:35)
        at trabalhoPoo.GameData.loadWeaponVendor(GameData.java:126)
        at trabalhoPoo.GameData.<init>(GameData.java:42)
        at trabalhoPoo.Game.<init>(Game.java:47)
        ... 13 more
Exception running application trabalhoPoo.Game
```

Comment: When you run a program in NetBeans, it will take care of the classpath for you. When running it from the command-line, you'll need to set the classpath so that Java knows where any additional JAR files you need are located.

You might also want to consider switching your project to Maven, which will (arguably) make all of this a little easier.

Comment: I would but i just realized this path problem and there's no time to change the Project.